# Gedit Click Config plugin won't open

Tags: linux, gnome, gtk, gedit, plugin

I'm using Gedit 3.4.2 with Click Config plugin 1.4.0. When I go to Edit->Click Config->Configure the window doesn't open, basically rendering this plugin useless. I've tried reinstalling the plugin. I've found a similar issue but I don't quite understand the fix: http://code.google.com/p/gedit-click-config/issues/detail?id=4

Comment: I did. ty: [http://code.google.com/p/gedit-click-config/issues/detail?id=14](http://code.google.com/p/gedit-click-config/issues/detail?id=14)

Answer (score 0):

I have posted a patch for it, you can check it out if it solves your problem:

http://code.google.com/p/gedit-click-config/issues/detail?id=16